# Restoring factory image of HP Laptop

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, system-restore, system-recovery

I use a HP G62. I am unable to use my recovery disk to restore to factory settings. I had no problems earlier until I created an additional partition which I hear might have changed my hard disk to dynamic.

How do I get back to 'normal'? I don't mind formatting the disk. I just want my factory OS back.

..............

I get an error message at about 69 percent telling me that the restoration process failed. I'm using the factory image disks I created using the HP recovery manager. I have tried formatting the hard drive clean and then restoring with the CD, it didn't work. I was always able to restore before I created that partition.

Comment: "I am unable to use my recovery disk to restore to factory settings". What does that mean? Don't you have the disk or are you having some problems restoring with it? How did you create an additional partition? What is your current partition layout? Be more specific, please.

Comment: Are you referring to the system restore partition that gets included on some laptops in lieu of CDs?

Comment: He is talking about a set of 3 or 4 dvds that you have to create. They back up the C:\ drive and the entire data in it.

Answer (score 2):

Use [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/) to nuke the hard disk, then use the recovery discs to restore it.

If it is Windows 7 and you are using HP-branded recovery discs, [see this page](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=pv_80183_1). You may need to make and run this disc first after you nuke the drive, then use the HP-branded recovery discs. If they are discs you made on the PC yourself, then this does not apply to you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my desktop, while browsing my old [Ghost](http://us.norton.com/ghost/) backup I saw a .gho image file which was hidden on the hard disk. I loaded a fresh copy with that .gho image file.

You can try to find if it exists. If it works, do not forget to get a fresh [Ghost](http://us.norton.com/ghost/) image for your own recovery solutions.

Comment: Ghost is not used by HP anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I have also been told I could use UBCD to copy the .wim file and transfer it from C:/ to drive D:/. Power down, reboot to BIOS and set boot device to whatever USB zip drive you have UBCD installed on. Using MiniXP you can recover from there too. DOUBLE CHECK EVERYTHING BEFORE PUSHING ANY COMMIT BUTTONS.
UBCD main page wil give you further instructions on this.